# Advice about INSERT statement performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I need to generate random numbers in SQL Server and write these codes into the table. I used the SQL statement as follows:

```
while (select count(code) from tb_random) <1000000
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @r int
set @r = rand()*10000000
insert into tb_random values(@r)
end
```

It takes over 20h to complete this query. Could you give me an idea to solve this performance problem?

Comment: Now that you have the numbers, do you need to do it again?  Also, you realize that you don't necessarily have unique numbers, right?

Comment: Actually, I need over 10,000,000 codes. It means that I have to repeat over 10 times. I know how to create the unique ID. I just concern about the performance and can apply other random algorithms. Thanks

Comment: whats ur tb_random schema?

Comment: Might be helpful if you tell us why you need this. This doesn't seem right to me, if we knew more you might end up with a simple solution...

Comment: Thank JBrooks. The ideas below helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 1 second for 1000000 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (Value int)
CREATE TABLE #tb_random (Value int)

insert into #Temp
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7),
(8),
(9),
(10)


insert into #tb_random
SELECT rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10000000

FROM #Temp as a
CROSS JOIN #Temp as b
CROSS JOIN #Temp as c
CROSS JOIN #Temp as d
CROSS JOIN #Temp as e
CROSS JOIN #Temp as f

DROP TABLE #Temp
DROP TABLE #tb_random
```

Add more cross joins for x10 results.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean yes, you are totally right! replace with #-table

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
declare @count int
set @count = 1
while @count < 1000000
begin
    insert into #example values(rand()*10000000)
    set @count = @count +1
end
```

Took about 35 seconds on my machine.

Comment: You can get rid .of the @r too.

Comment: Thanks @JimHewitt. It's useful.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you commit every insert. Commit implies flush to disk, so your script does ... nothing for 99% of the time. It just sits and waits for the disk to flush. Commit in batches:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @count int = 0
declare @r int;
begin transaction;
while @count <1000000
begin
  set @r = rand()*10000000;
  insert into tb_random values(@r);
  set @count += 1;
  if @count % 1000 = 0
  begin
    commit;
    begin tran;
  end
end
commit;
```

Comment: Thanks Remus. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

This run in 5 seconds on my notebook:

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 
            rn = IDENTITY(int, 1, 1), 
            random_int = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000000 + 1
INTO #random_numbers
FROM sys.all_columns AS t1
     CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS t2;

SELECT * FROM #random_numbers;
```

Comment: Thanks Igor for my references.